# stringr in R: extract filename from filename.extension when filename and filename.extension share common chars

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have a set of 'filename.extension's and I want to extract just the filename. I am having trouble extracting the full filename when the filename shares a character with the file extension.  for example, the filename.extension "qrs.sas7bdat" has

```
    filename="qrs"
    extension="sas7bdat"
```

In this case one may observe that the filename shares in common with the extension the character "s".

Here's some R code to give more context:

```
files_sas <- c("abc.sas7bdat","qrs.sas7bdat")
stringr::str_extract(files_sas,"(?:.*|.*s)[^\\.sas7bdat]")
```

This set of code returns the following character vector:

```
"abc" "qr"
```

This is not what I want -- the desired result I want follows:

```
c("abc","qrs")
```

It looks like I'm close, and so I am hoping someone might be able to help me get my desired result.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `sub` to match the `.` (`.` is a metacharacter that matches any character, so we escape (`\\`) iit, followed by other character (`.*`), in the replacement, we can specify blank (`""`)

```
sub("\\..*", "", files_sas)
#[1] "abc" "qrs"
```

---

Or with `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
str_remove(files_sas, "\\..*")
```

---

Or with `file_path_sans_ext`

```
tools::file_path_sans_ext(files_sas)
#[1] "abc" "qrs"
```

Comment: The first two variants can not handle filenames with dots. Those are widely allowed. Therefore I would only recommend your third variant, the regex inside of the source code of `file_path_sans_ext` is more complicated than `"\\..*"` for this very reason. For completeness: `sub("([^.]+)\\.[[:alnum:]]+$", "\\1", x)`